# .htaccess Redirect a subdirectory to its index.php file

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I've been stuck on this one for a long long time. I will try to explain the problem but feel free to ask for more details if it is not clearly explained.

I have two directories, the document root directory and the **cms** subdirectory. What I am trying to do is to redirect every URL without a subdirectory in it (for example domain.com, domain.com/help) to the index.php of the root directory and in the same time to redirect every URL containing the *cms* subdirectory (example - domain.com/cms/item) to the index.php of the *cms* directory. This is my .htaccess file but sadly it is not working:

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!cms/)(.+)$ /index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^cms/(.+)$ /cms/index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated as this is a crucial part of the project and it is required as index.php files handle the SEO and include the required files.

Comment: Change the order of your rules, match `^cms/(.+)$` first, and use only `^(.+)$` for the second one …

Comment: Or use `^([^/]+)$` for the second one, if you want to exclude _all_ directories (i.e., allow only paths that do not contain a `/`.)

Comment: @04FS Thanks for your response. Sadly when I try to access a file in the cms subfolder it still accesses directly the file instead of accessing index.php of /cms.

Comment: You mean an actually existing file? Those you excluded from rewriting, with the RewriteConds there you are checking that what was requested was _not_ an existing file.

Comment: @04FS yeah, the structure of my URLs in my cms is 'domain.com/cms/users.php', while in the public part it is like 'domain.com/about'. The idea is to include the existing files in index.php of /cms while retaining the URL in the URL bar. The public part is working flawlessly.

Comment: So what exactly is not working now? If `/cms/users.php` _exists_, and you still want to rewrite this to `/cms/index.php?u=users.php` - then of course that RewriteCond checking if what was requested does _not_ match an existing file has to be removed.

Comment: (You might need to add a check, that the current internal request URI is _not_ `cms/index.php` though, so that this doesn’t create an endless loop at this point.)

Comment: Right now the '''/cms/users.php''' file exists and loads with errors because, in order to work properly, it must be included in the index.php of '''/cms'''